# I saw him take and I thought he arrive

Tags: word-usage, catenative-verbs

Can someone explain to me the grammatical rule for:

1. I ***thought*** he ***knew*** it
2. I ***saw*** him ***arrive***

Why use past tense (knew) for one,and present for another (arrive)

Answer (score 0):

The verb in the second sentence is "saw", which has the past tense verb "saw". "him arrive" is a clause with an infinitive, which is unconjugated, that is, it is not present tense.
The first example is not comparable, because it has a separate past tense clause "he knew it", which is the direct object of "thought".

Comment: Note that the subordinate clause in the first one is a "that" clause (which always has a finite (tensed) verb), even though the "that" may be omitted. _I thought that he knew it_ would be equally good. The second one, with an infinitive clause cannot have "that".